# Building Objective-C environment on Windows through Sublime Text

Tags: objective-c, gcc, build, sublimetext2

I'm trying to create a building environment using Sublime Text as editor and Windows 7 as OS. I have installed properly GNUstep to build `Objective-c` program on Windows but every time I have to build and execute a program I have to open `cmd` and write

```
gcc -o helloworld.exe helloworld.m -I /GNUstep/GNUstep/System/Library/Headers -L /GNUstep/GNUstep/System/Library/Libraries -std=c99 -lobjc -lgnustep-base -fconstant-string-class=NSConstantString
```

I have found Sublime Text give the chance to write building customized instructions to compile program inside the program itself but I don't know how to write this instructions.

This is the blank build file in Sublime Text I have to complete

```
{
    "cmd": ["make"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [documentation on build systems](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_processing/build_systems.html), making sure to follow the link at the bottom to the [Build System Reference](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html) for starters. [Build System Variables](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html#build-system-variables) will help you construct your command so you can name your executable the same as your source, if you wish. For example, you can use something like the following to start (I'll leave it up to you to fill in the rest):

```json
{
    "cmd": ["gcc", "$file", "-o", "${file/\.m/\.exe/}", "etc. etc. etc."]
}
```